# What is the most efficient way to make instance real and joined

Tags: instances

[image]

I have a setup, a very complex instancing, I simply want to Voxel Remesh this (sculpt) but if I use Make Real for instances, it will create bazillions instances, and I don't want that. I simply need a joined mesh based on the parented dupli instances, regardles how complex, and from that single mesh, then I can use Voxel Remesh or other processing.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Make real and join***

Could make the mesh by making the dupliobject active and running make duplicates real, and then joining them.  *Sorry haven't fixed the location properly*

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
vl = context.view_layer

obs = set(scene.objects)
bpy.ops.object.duplicates_make_real()
new_obs = list(set(scene.objects) - obs)
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
o = new_obs[0]
vl.objects.active = o
for o in new_obs:
    o.select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.join()
```

**Using depsgraph in 2.8**

[image]
*Result in edit mode above, default torus duplivert default and scaled down icosphere.  May be cuppa time while it runs*

Instances can be obtained from the depsgraph. https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.DepsgraphObjectInstance.html#module-bpy.types

There is a section in

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API

re getting the instances of an object via the python API.

Using the method prescribed for getting instances of a particular object, here is a test script to create a bmesh from all object instances of the context object,

The bmesh is written to  new single mesh object from the instances.  The mesh equivalent of make real and join.  (*Without the original*)

I have only tested this on a very simple example, without materials.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
mwi = ob.matrix_world.inverted()
dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

bm = bmesh.new()
for ob_inst in dg.object_instances:
    if ob_inst.parent and ob_inst.parent.original == ob:
        me = ob_inst.instance_object.data
        bm.from_mesh(me)
        # transform to match instance
        bmesh.ops.transform(bm,
                matrix=mwi @ ob_inst.matrix_world,
                verts=bm.verts[-len(me.vertices):]
                )

# link an object with the instanced mesh

me = bpy.data.meshes.new(f"{ob.data.name}_InstanceMesh")
bm.to_mesh(me)
ob_ev = bpy.data.objects.new(f"{ob.name}_InstancedObject", me) 
ob_ev.matrix_world = ob.matrix_world

context.collection.objects.link(ob_ev)
```

Comment: Interesting, appreciate the post. Works like a charm but still takes a few seconds for ~500 spheres on my machine though.

Comment: Thankyou. Could try without the `bmesh` by generating using `from_pydata`, with some `numpy` trickery  Hence prob not most efficient,   Added the operator approach with make real then join.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! This works well and faster than "making copy real" and joining it back.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that

bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')

will apply the visual mesh and remove all the modifiers, linked or not.  handy for cleaning up linked modifiers after making all instances real.

you can find it on ctrl+a as "apply visual mesh"