# Is there a low-level version of 'duplicates_make_real()?

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a low-level version of the operator `bpy.ops.object.duplicates_make_real()`? 
I really want to avoid using `ops` in my script for efficiency.

Comment: If you can select multiple objects that have duplis and call the operator once to create all it may be more efficient than using API methods.  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149264/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-make-instance-real-and-joined

Comment: I'm already only calling the bpy.ops.object.duplicates_make_real() once on a vertsdupli object with 100k verts and it's super slow.