# How to retrieve dupli data in 2.8?

Tags: python, dupli-groups

In 2.79 there is `dupli_list_create` and bunch of attributes to get from it:

https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.DupliObject.html#bpy.types.DupliObject

According to the change log it was removed in recent version:

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/change_log.html?highlight=dupli_list

*What is analog for 2.8?*

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149269/15543

Comment: Thanks, I've found an answer in your links.

Answer (score 1):

From *batFINGERS*' [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149269/29200):

> Instances can be obtained from the depsgraph.
>   https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.DepsgraphObjectInstance.html#module-bpy.types
>
> There is a section in
>
> https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API

So, `bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get().object_instances` is a replacement for `bpy.context.object.dupli_list`