# bmesh transforming multiple objects into a single mesh (separate objects)

Tags: transforms, bmesh

I am trying to duplicate multiple objects resulting in the same location/rotation relative to each other. I can get my code to work for a single object but when multiple objects are used obviously the objects get transformed N times (N number of multiple objects). Is there a function that I am missing or a different approach?

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bm = bmesh.new()
for i, o in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects): 
    bm.from_mesh(o.data)
    bm.transform(o.matrix_world)
    
    
me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Mesh")
bm.to_mesh(me)
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Object", me) # https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

[image: Objects to be copied]
[image: Output Transformed with o.matrix_world]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`bm.transform` transforms every vert.**

Question code will be getting an accumulative effect of transforming every current vert in the `bmesh` by each objects world matrix.

Instead, only transform the newly "from_mesh'd" vertices

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bm = bmesh.new()

for i, o in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects): 
    bm.from_mesh(o.data)
    bmesh.ops.transform(
            bm,
            verts = bm.verts[-len(o.data.vertices):],
            matrix=o.matrix_world,
            )

            
me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Mesh")
bm.to_mesh(me)
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Object", me) # https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

Related

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149269/15543

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that you could apply the transforms to verts! Thanks again :)